# when to escape data when php returns json

Tags: php

When is it better to escape data in json (to avoid cross-site scripting)?
1. To return escaped data
2. To escape in javascript when we use json to update page.

I try to escape on server, but some jquery functions escape data too, so after update of page
data looks different.

Comment: The general rule for escaping is always to escape exactly when needed, no sooner, no later. Escaping for some possible client-side problems on the server is largely non-sensical.

Answer (score 5):

Data formats should be kept as clean as possible. Put the raw data in the JSON. Escape it only when JSON requires it (e.g. when you have a `"` character in a string).

When you take the data out of JSON and put it somewhere else (e.g. in an HTML document, into the DOM, into an SQL query, etc) then escape it appropriately for where you are putting it.

Comment: Could you please tell how do escape values on javascript before updating page? It looks sometimes some methods of jquery does escaping.

Comment: Basically it comes down to learning which functions expect you to pass them text (they will do escaping for you) and which expect you to pass HTML (they won't).